# How to use Rolle's Theorem to show that $f$ has at most one fixed point? NOT DUPLICATE

Tags: real-analysis, rolles-theorem

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $a\lt b $. Suppose that $f:[a,b]→\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and that

$f'(x) \gt 1$ , for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Use Rolle's Theorem to show that $f$ has at most one fixed point in (a,b), that is a point $x_o\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$.

Hint: You may find it helpful to argue using proof by contradiction.

My solution so far:

Rolle's Theorem states that if $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and that $f(a)=f(b)$, then there is a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

Assume for a contradiction, there are two fixed points in $(a,b)$, that is, $x_0,x_1\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$ and $f(x_1)=x_1$.

Now, I don't know how to proceed from this because $f(x_0)\ne f(x_1)$, so surely you can't apply Rolle's Theorem here.

Note: This is not a duplicate question as this question explicitly asks to use Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$.  Suppose $g$ has two zeroes.

Comment: @nicomezi Yes, sorry. I forgot to mention $f(a)=f(b)$ in Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: I was talking about the first statement, I have missed the "at most".

Comment: The "duplicate" is not one, this question asks for a solution with Rolle's theorem.

Comment: @nicomezi To be fair, the accepted answer for the linked question uses the mean value theorem.  Rolle's theorem (particularly the way that Rudin proves it, if I recall correctly) is really just a special case of MVT when the two endpoints evaluate to zero.

Comment: That being said, perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324783/f-colon-a-b-to-a-b-continuous-has-exactly-one-fixed-point-if-fx-neq) would be a better dupe target.